# Cannot connect my heroku app with command line interface(CLI)

Tags: git, heroku, command-line-interface, backend, web-testing

I do have the app on Heroku server but I cannot connect to it with Heroku Command Line

This is the command I am running in PowerShell

`heroku git:remote -a todo-dennis`

This is the output

```
Error: Command failed: git remote
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The command you're running adds a remote to an already cloned copy of your repository, while your error message indicates that you are not in a repository at all (there is no `.git` folder). You would use this command if you already have a local clone that isn't yet configured with a `heroku` remote for you to push to.

If you don't have a of your repo yet, then clone one instead:

```
heroku git:clone -a todo-dennis
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app